# Wii accelerometer data ranges

Tags: python, wii

I have 2 related questions, please.

I am using a wiimote on a robotics project and I need to convert **X** and **Y** values into new bounded values.

So, give the following accelerometer data:

```
[X]: 2.17925555556
[Y]: -6.53776666667
[Z]: -0.754357692308
```

**[1]** I need to convert/map **X** to between *-0.22* and *0.22*, **Y** to *-2.84* and *2.84*.

To accomplish the conversion/mapping, I'm told I need the range of X and Y accelerometer data.

**[2]** Does anyone know what the range of accelerometer data is on a wiimote?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. What API are you using to interface with the Wiimote? The [raw accelerometer hardware](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote#Accelerometer) has 10 bits of precision for X & 9 for Y & Z. I'm guessing the values you're getting have been massaged by library code.

Comment: @Pikalek: Hi. I am using the Wiimote ROS package

Comment: Just want to clarify, are you referring to [this Wiimote ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/wiimote)?

Comment: @Pikalek: That's the one

Comment: @Pikalek: By the way, if you happen to have expertise on how to properly read the wiimote accelerometer data using the Wiimote ROS package, I would appreciate you enlightening me. MERRY CHRISTMAS!

Comment: I'm not a robotics expert or familiar with the API you're using. Having skimmed the API, I could attempt to answer, but I suspect what you want might be a bad idea. Rather than have me or other game devs speculate, this question might be better suited to the [Robotics SE](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/) where more relevant expertise could be applied. I skimmed [their guidelines](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) & it looks like it would be on-top there. If you want it over there instead, [request to have it migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/228147).